# Constructing a object based on a string value

Tags: java

I've been working on reflection within my Tower Defense game but I'm struggling to get this one working right.

First here's the context:
We are working within processing, this is a requirement from the school. We may not import any additional libraries.

The object I am trying to construct is first received as a string from the menu. From there I convert it into a class value and from there I want to place the tower at its proper location. Code of the method provided below along with a switch which is our legacy method.

```
    void spawnSelected(String selectedTower) {
    selectedTower = ENGINE_PREFIX + selectedTower;
    try{
      Class c = Class.forName(selectedTower);
      println(c);
      try{
        Constructor C = c.getConstructor(PVector.class);
        println(C);
        //C.newInstance();
      /*}catch(InstantiationException s){
        println(s);
      }catch(IllegalAccessException r){
        println(r);
      */}catch(NoSuchMethodException p){
        println(p);
      }catch(ReflectiveOperationException i){
        println(i);
      }
    }catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
      println(e);
    }

    /*switch(selectedTower) {
    case "air_tower":
      new air_tower(mp.drawLocation);
      break;
    case "dark_tower":
      new dark_tower(mp.drawLocation);
      break;
    case "fire_tower":
      new fire_tower(mp.drawLocation);
      break;
    case "light_tower":
      new light_tower(mp.drawLocation);
      break;
    case "nature_tower":
      new nature_tower(mp.drawLocation);
      break;
    case "water_tower":
      new water_tower(mp.drawLocation);
      break;
    default: 
      selectedTower ="Air_tower";
      break;
    }*/
  }
```

I'll show the constructor for the air tower:

```
  class air_tower extends Basic_Tower {
  air_tower(PVector Loc){
   super( Loc ); 
   cost = 100;
   String[] effects = {
   };

   int[] effectEffectivenes = {
   };
   img =  loadImage("Air.png");
   type = "air";
   projectileSpeed = 360;
   projectileAcceleration = 5;
   range = 175;
   fireRate = 1400;
   damage = 27.5;
   numberOfTargets = 1;
   AoE = 0;
  }
}
```

I reckon that the basic_tower constructor may also be relevant. So here it is:

```
 Basic_Tower(PVector Loc) {
```

This guy extends object, which is our most basic object possible. That guy has an empty constructor.

My try-catch comes back with this error:

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: Basic_TowerDefense_Engine$air_tower.(processing.core.PVector)

Does anyone see what I am doing wrong?

UPDATE:
So I attempted to use the function getConstructors()
When I did the return was an empty array. This is a lead that I will start researching now.

Comment: NoSuchMethodException: Basic_TowerDefense_Engine$air_tower : you're missing a method.

Comment: Is `air_tower` an inner class of `Basic_TowerDefense_Engine`?

Comment: @CocoNess But shoulden't getConstructor always fetch the objects constructor? Which I have defined.

Comment: @Mureinik Yes, it is. That is why I add the engine prefix in every-case.

Comment: @Henry Could you elaborate some of the terms that you used here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first argument of an inner class's constructor is implicitly its enclosing class:

```
Constructor con = 
    c.getConstructor(Basic_TowerDefense_Engine.class, PVector.class);
con.newInstance(this /* presumably? */, mp.drawLocation);
```

Asker note: Please read the comments for further context regarding the issue, and how the resolution came to be.

Comment: Hmm, unfortunately that does not seem to work. Just creating that con already results in the following error: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: Basic_TowerDefense_Engine$air_tower.<init>(Basic_TowerDefense_Engine, processing.core.PVector)

Comment: Something intresting I just stumbled across. The getconstructors function returns nothing at all. Might this be an indicator to you what is wrong?

Comment: @TDSrock Didn't notice the modifiers, how daft of me. Can you try changing `air_tower`'s constructor to public?

Comment: Jup I essentially went on the same though process as soon as I posted and came too the conclusion. Thanks for the help though! :)

Answer (score 0):

Welp I got it to work.

Turns out the fact that I did not explicitly state public in my construtors meant that .getConstructors could not find anything at all.

However when I placed public it was recognized. From there combining what I already had + the answer provided by @Mureinik I got the final answer.

resulting in the following code for the constructor and the init of the obj.

```
Constructor C = c.getConstructor(Basic_TowerDefense_Engine.class, PVector.class);
C.newInstance(head, mp.drawLocation);
```

Where head is the Basc_TowerDefense_Engine object.